# Jasmine spyOn objects inside anonymous callback function

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need to unit test a `controller` function`saveSettings()` as shown below. I want to test if `Session.setUrl()` is being called or not on success. How can I achieve that?

```
angular.module("test.controllers")
    .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, Validator, Session, Notify){

        $scope.apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/web-server/";

        $scope.saveSettings = function () {

             Validator.validateUrl($scope.apiUrl, 
                  function (url) { // success callback function
                      Session.setUrl(url);
                  }, 
                  function (error) { // failure callback function
                      Notify.alert('' + error);
                  }
            );
        };
    });
```

And the service is defined as follows:

```
angular.module('test.services')
  .service('Validator', function () {

      this.validateUrl = function(url, success, error) {

          if ( !url ) {

              error("URL not found!");
          } else {

               if (url.startsWith('http') && !url.startsWith('https')) {
                   url = url.replace('http', 'https');
               }
               success(url);
          }
      };
  });
```

In the following test code (courtesy of: @Etse), `Session.setUrl()` is not being called:

```
describe('LoginCtrl', function(){
    beforeEach(module('test.controllers');
    beforeEach(inject($controller){
        this.scope = {};
        this.controller = $controller('LoginCtrl', {$scope: this.scope});
    });

    it('should call setUrl on success', inject(function(Session){
        spyOn(Validator, 'validateUrl');
        spyOn(Session, 'setUrl');
        this.scope.saveSettings();
        expect(Validator.validateUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(Session.setUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
})
```

**SOLVED** by adding `callThrough()` as follows:

```
spyOn(Validator, "validateUrl").and.callThrough();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume Sessions is a Service, as you are using dependency injection to get it? It should be possible to just add a normal spy on the service - aslong as you inject it into the test aswell.

In my test I just setup the controller, and expose the scope on the this-conext - this way I get access to it in my tests.

I found some errors in the code, and rewrote it.

- I found some missing parantheses
- $scope not injected in controller
- Added module dependencies

Here is a working code example:

```js
angular.module('test.services', [])
  .service('Session', function(){
    this.setUrl = function() {
       console.log("test");
    };
  })
  .service('Validator', function () {
      this.validateUrl = function(url, success, error) {
          if ( !url ) {
              error("URL not found!");
          } else {
               if (url.startsWith('http') && !url.startsWith('https')) {
                   url = url.replace('http', 'https');
               }
               success(url);
          }
      };
  });

angular.module("test.controllers", ['test.services'])
    .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, Validator, Session){
        $scope.apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/web-server/";
        $scope.saveSettings = function () {
             Validator.validateUrl($scope.apiUrl, 
                  function (url) { // success callback function
                      Session.setUrl(url);
                  }, 
                  function (error) { // failure callback function
                      console.log("notify");
                  }
            );
        };
    });


//--- SPECS -------------------------
describe('LoginCtrl', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
      module("test.controllers");
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller){
        this.scope = {};
        this.controller = $controller('LoginCtrl', {$scope: this.scope});
    }));

    it('should call setUrl on success', inject(function(Session){
        spyOn(Session, 'setUrl');
        this.scope.saveSettings();
        expect(Session.setUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="http://searls.github.io/jasmine-all/jasmine-all-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, Session is a service. The test logic, in your code, is what I am expecting here.

Comment: okey, you just need to setup the controller in a beforeEach and call the saveSettings on the scope. Looking at your implementation, that should call the success-callback as the URL is valid.

Comment: I've just updated the question including your proposed solution. The success callback is not being called with my code as shown in the updated question.

Comment: I found some errors in the code. The new code in the answer works on jsfiddle

Comment: It's just a code snippet. agreed on the missing $scope injection. It seems like the problem was because I was also spying on Validator.validateUrl(). It worked after I added and.callThrough(). Anyways, I really appreciate your response and going to accept your answer. Thanks a lot.